# add path to file zshrc

Tags: android, flutter, macos, zshrc

How can I add the path address of Flutter and Android in the zshrc file? (on Mac)
To run the application (android or flutter) on the phone

I added both addresses manually, but it always understands only one of them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please! Provide more information or the code to make your question more understandable.